# Как отключить корректировку кода в браузере Chrom

Tags: google-chrome, браузер

Как запретить проверку кода браузером Chrom? Чтобы он сам не правил ничего, а если есть ошибка то крашился, ломался. А то невозможно ошибку свою найти самому, когда ее браузер поправил. Гугл пока не подсказал мне ответ, надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: Если Вы об ошибках в HTML, то настройте нормально свой IDE/Code Editor чтобы он подчеркивал и обнаруживал Ваши ошибки, так же можете использовать [Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/). Насколько я знаю, как пользователь, Вы не можете этого отключить, потому что таким образом работают современные браузеры.

Comment: Добрый день. Chom сам пытается исправить ошибки в html. Мне нужно чтобы он этого не делал. Можно ли это отключить?

Comment: Это нельзя отключить, насколько я знаю, я же написал выше. Используйте валидаторы HTML.